# Sql delete not appearing to work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running delete sql in Managment Studio 2008 and it indicated to me the sql has worked....but it hasnt.

For example

```
select count(*) from MyTable where  [MYkey] =24
```

returns 1

```
delete from MyTable where  [MYkey] =  24
```

Rows Affected 1

But if I immediately run the first statement again, the record is still there. If I try an `update` statement, that works. I am seeing this behaviour on all tables in the database.

I had a few issues with the Transaction log being full a few days ago, I change the recovery model to simple. Could this be related? If so what do I need to do?

Comment: Maybe some transaction issue? Did you commit the transaction?

Comment: Are there any triggers that insert into this table from another table? It could be that you delete, trigger inserts what you deleted.

Comment: @Uwe Kiem. ok maybe? What do you mean? I just ran the statements with `go` inbetween. How do I commit the transaction?

Comment: @Dan try to do it with subquery : `delete from MyTable where  [MYkey] in (SELECT [MyKey]  from MyTable where [MyKey] %24<>0 and [MYkey]  not in (75062897,719192179))`

Comment: @Dan I'm not saying _that_ there are transactions involved, I just wanted to point out that you should be aware of transactions which _might_ be the cause. I had similar issues with Oracle SQL Developer in the past.

Comment: @r.piesnikowski No its more fundamental than that. I have simplified my question to illustrate this.

Comment: @Uwe sure I agree. I was just asking, how I go about making sure transactions aren't/are invovled?

Comment: Is the issue isolated to just one table?

Comment: Are you sure delete runs without error? Maybe there is a foreign key.

Comment: No the delete runs without error. Management studio responds with the "Row Affected xxx" message.

Comment: Is it possible to backup the DB and restore it either under a different name or on a different server instance or computer? Then truncate the log and try some deletes again. That way you would be able to determine whether the issue *is* related to the log being full.

Comment: Does the user have permission to delete?

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  delete from MyTable where  [MYkey] =  24;
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: what do you get when you run the select statement - 
      select * from MyTable where  [MYkey] =  24

Comment: The row comes back. The delete is not working/or not being committed somehow.

Comment: Yeah, I tried wrapping it in a transaction - that did not help either :(