# SQL DELETE appears to work but then does not implement changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a table of Cards that so far contains 10 rows. if I execute:

```
delete from [Card] where cardnumber = 00010 //this card being held in the last row
```

I get the resulting message (1 row(s) affected), which I would expect works, however upon opening the table I find that the row is still there.

Next I used Edit Top 200 Rows in SSMS to select the row manually and delete it, upon which it is removed from the table, but when I execute, the row is back in the table.

Finally, I created a stored procedure that returns a success when executed, but the changes are still not being kept.

What is strange however, is that I have a CardAmount table with a relationship to the Card table that holds points per card, and the cards are being removed from CardAmount.

I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241630/sql-delete-not-appearing-to-work) question, but I don't think that was ever resolved.

Comment: What data type is the cardnumber field? Having = 00010 is a bit odd.

Comment: Additionally - are there any triggers on this table that might be interrupting your delete?

Comment: First guess would be an `instead of delete` trigger that forgot to actually affect the table it's meant to be performing the delete for.

Comment: Are you using a program that requires you to commit the changes (to make them permanent)?

Comment: Things can you check: 1) Is the transaction commited? 2) There's a trigger instead of or re-creating the row? 3) Some other process/bl is re-creating that row (something like to "insert it if it's not exists")

Comment: @Paddy the data type of CardNumber is nvarchar, which is a little unusual but suits the purpose of the column. However, I have a primary key ID which is int, but that does not work either.

Comment: I completely forgot about the trigger! @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right, there is an instead of delete that is not affecting the table, just CardAmount. Thank you everyone for replying so quickly! :)

Comment: I suggest @Damien_The_Unbeliever post an answer since he solved the answer as a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First guess (which turned out to be correct) would be an `instead of delete` trigger that forgot to actually affect the table it's meant to be performing the delete for.

This is a common error, especially if you're implementing some far reaching form of cascade (and can't just use `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the foreign key constraint) where you have to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger but then neglect to perform the `DELETE` on the underlying table.

Comment: This problem resulted from my error, but this answer will be useful to others. Thanks again!